# How to do reverse slicing method on a string

Tags: python, string, reverse

I have a alphabet string like:

```
string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

if  want to do slicing and and go from z to a but with 3 steps. what should I do? I know `string[::-1]` will reverse it but how can I make it go by 3 steps each time?

I have done it by assigning a new string which is reverse of the other string and do slicing with 3 steps from there. I'm looking for a new way to do it without changing the previous string and doing it on the same spot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: What's the desired output? Also, strings are immutaable so you can't modify it in place.

Comment: Surely `string[::-3] ` is a natural try -- did you *try* it? The Python shell allows for quick experimentation, which can give you an answer much more quickly than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The last number in the slice is the interval:

```
string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
string[::-3]
'zwtqnkheb'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 3 letter slices starting from the end and going backward, you can use a list comprehension:

```
string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
slices =  [ string[i:i+3][::-1] for i in range(len(string)-3,0,-3) ]

# ['zyx', 'wvu', 'tsr', 'qpo', 'nml', 'kji', 'hgf', 'edc']
```